# CNN weights at input image location

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch

Given a CNN, say AlexNet: 
[image: AlexNet]

How could one relate kernel locations at the 3rd conv block, i.e 13x13 filter size to the input image. I want to compare the filters at different locations. 
I was thinking of just bilinearly upsampling the location, from 13x13 to 224x224,

```
nn.Upsample(size = (224,224), mode='bilinear')
```

however it's hard to justify local correspondence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using adaptive pooling, with adaptive pooling, one can reduce any feature map size.

[Adaptive max pooling](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/pooling.html)